# Is there any date function in hive 1.1 to find out month difference like months_between or datediff(month,day1,day2)

Tags: hiveql, datediff, cloudera-cdh

I was trying to find out month difference between 2 dates say `2019-04-01` and `2018-11-01` but I am not to use `months_between` or `datediff(month, day1, day2)` functions as its not available on hive1.1.

Getting below error:

> Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10011]: Line 1:7 Invalid function 'months_between' (state=42000,code=10011)
>
> Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10015]: Line 1:7 Arguments length mismatch ''01'': datediff() requires 2 argument, got 3 (state=21000,code=10015)

Any one has faced such issue ? Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

What about month(day1) - month(day2).
Have you tried that?

Comment: I tried it but this will not take of different years right.. like how about  march 2018 - oct 2017..?

Answer (score 0):

year(day1)*12 + month(day1) - year(day2)*12 - month(day2)

Comment: Hi, it would be great if you can also provide an explanation how this would work and why the OP's approach fails :)